# Calling recursive function in loop with async/await and Promise.all

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, recursion

I have a use case where I'm trying to loop through an array of objects, where I need to make some GraphQL requests that may have some pagination for a given object in the array. I'm trying to speed up performance by pushing the recursive function to an array of promises, and then use `Promse.all` to resolve all of those.

I'm running into an issue though where I'm getting an `undefined` response from `Promise.all` - The end goal is to have the following response for each unique object in the array:

```
[{
  account: test1,
  id: 1,
  high: 2039,
  critical: 4059
},
{
  account: test2,
  id: 2,
  high: 395,
  critical: 203
}]
```

...where I'm only returning `anAccount` object after recursion is done paginating/making all requests for a given account object.

Here is the sample code:

```
const fetch = require('isomorphic-fetch');
const API_KEY = '<key>';

async function main() {
  let promises = [];

  let accounts = [{'name': 'test1', 'id': 1}, {'name': 'test2' , 'id': 2}];

  for (const a of accounts) {
    let cursor = null;
    let anAccountsResults = [];
    promises.push(getCounts(a, anAccountsResults, cursor));
  }

  let allResults = await Promise.all(promises);
  console.log(allResults);
}

async function getCounts(acct, results, c) {
  var q = ``;

  if (c == null) {
    q = `{
        actor {
          account(id: ${acct.id}) {
            aiIssues {
              issues(filter: {states: ACTIVATED}) {
                issues {
                  issueId
                  priority
                }
                nextCursor
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }`
  } else {
    q = `{
        actor {
          account(id: ${acct.id}) {
            aiIssues {
              issues(filter: {states: ACTIVATED}, cursor: "${c}") {
                issues {
                  issueId
                  priority
                }
                nextCursor
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }`
  }

  const resp = await fetch('https://my.api.com/graphql', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'API-Key': API_KEY
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        query: q,
    variables: ''}),
  });

  let json_resp = await resp.json();

  let aSingleResult = json_resp.data.actor.account.aiIssues.issues.issues;
  let nextCursor = json_resp.data.actor.account.aiIssues.issues.nextCursor;
  console.log(nextCursor);

  if (nextCursor == null) {
    results = results.concat(aSingleResult);
  } else {
    results = results.concat(aSingleResult);
    await getCounts(acct, results, nextCursor);
  }

  let criticalCount = results.filter(i => i.priority == 'CRITICAL').length;
  let highCount = results.filter(i => i.priority == 'HIGH').length;

  let anAccount = {
        account: acct.name,
        id: acct.id,
        high: highCount,
        critical: criticalCount
      };

 return anAccount;
}

main();
```

logging `anAccount` in function `getCounts` has the correct detail, but when returning it, logging the output of `Promise.all(promises)` yields `undefined`. Is there a better way to handle this in a way where I can still asynchronously run multiple recursive functions in parallel within the loop with `Promise.all`?

Comment: The console.log prints undefined, not an array of undefined ? This seems really weird

Comment: Instead of collecting things into a `results` array that you pass an a parameter, better have every call **return** a new array. Then in the recursive `await getCounts(acct, results, nextCursor)` call, do not ignore the return value.

Comment: Your main problem appears to be that `results = results.concat(aSingleResult);` does not mutate the array you passed, but only reassigns the local variable `results` inside the function, which you never use for anything.

Comment: I'm using the final `results` to get the correct counts based on the 2 filters. Are you saying in the `for` loop within `main()`, I should be storing a new array every time into a variable in that scope?

Comment: Ah, right, I didn't spot those. But even that isn't the correct result, since it only counts those from the first `aSingleResult` and not those from the recursive calls.

Comment: So the following changes made it successful: moving the declaration of `anAccountsResults` out of the array in `main` and using `return` within the recursive function instead of using `await`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main problem appears to be that `results = results.concat(aSingleResult);` does not mutate the array you passed, but only reassigns the local variable results inside the function, so the `anAccount` only will use the `aSingleResult` from the current call.
Instead of collecting things into a results array that you pass an a parameter, better have every call return a new array. Then in the recursive await getCounts(acct, results, nextCursor) call, do not ignore the return value.

```
async function main() {
  let promises = [];

  const accounts = [{'name': 'test1', 'id': 1}, {'name': 'test2' , 'id': 2}];

  const promises = accounts.map(async acct => {
    const results = await getIssues(acct);
    const criticalCount = results.filter(i => i.priority == 'CRITICAL').length;
    const highCount = results.filter(i => i.priority == 'HIGH').length;
    return {
      account: acct.name,
      id: acct.id,
      high: highCount,
      critical: criticalCount
    };
  });
  const allResults = await Promise.all(promises);
  console.log(allResults);
}


const query = `query ($accountId: ID!, $cursor: IssuesCursor) {
  actor {
    account(id: $accountId) {
      aiIssues {
        issues(filter: {states: ACTIVATED}, cursor: $cursor) {
          issues {
            issueId
            priority
          }
          nextCursor
        }
      }
    }
  }
}`;

async function getIssues(acct, cursor) {
  const resp = await fetch('https://my.api.com/graphql', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'API-Key': API_KEY
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      query: q,
      variables: {
        accountId: acct.id,
        cursor,
      }
    }),
  });
  if (!resp.ok) throw new Error(resp.statusText);
  const { data, error } = await resp.json();
  if (error) throw new Error('GraphQL error', {cause: error});

  const { nextCursor, issues } = data.actor.account.aiIssues.issues;
  if (nextCursor == null) {
    return issues;
  } else {
    return issues.concat(await getIssues(acct, nextCursor));
  }
}
```